# Fastest way to randomly permute only a subset of indices (akin to non-black pixels) in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, permutation

I have a 3D numpy array of shape, e.g.: (500,500,3), with only some [i,j,:] cells that are zero across all 3 channels (imagine an RGB image with all channels being zero = black pixel). What is the fastest way to perform an in-place permutation of these values, so that 'all zero' [i,j] cells remain so post-permutation (in the image example, black pixels remain black, all the rest permuted).

Here is an example of such an array, along with a working solution (but I would like it to be as fast as possible):

```
# make the numpy array
a = np.zeros((500,500,3))
a[100:200,100:200] = 1
a[200:300,200:300] = 2

# extract (i,j) indices and corresponding RGB values for indices that are not all zero RGB
idx_to_val = {idx[:-1]: a[idx[:-1]] for idx, _ in np.ndenumerate(a) if sum(a[idx[:-1]]) > 0}
idx, vals = list(idx_to_val.keys()), list(idx_to_val.values())

# shuffle the (i,j) indices
np.random.shuffle(idx)

# fill in a new numpy array at these not-all-zero indices with the non-shuffled values 
a_perm = np.zeros(a.shape)
a_perm[tuple(zip(*idx))] = vals
```

Any ideas for a faster solution would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully vectorized solution based on [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```py
a_perm = np.zeros_like(a)
rows, cols = np.where(a.any(axis=-1))
perm = np.random.permutation(len(rows))
a_perm[rows[perm], cols[perm]] = a[rows, cols]
```

Comment: Nearly - for some reason a_perm[100:200, 100:200] has zeros in it (it should only have a mixture of [1,1,1] or [2,2,2] there).

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. My edited answer should work fine.